# how to give priority to csv files in hotfolder?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hotfolder

If I have some *CSV* files and I want to give them priority as per my requirement in **Hotfolder**,
What to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the role of **FileOrderComparator** that compares files based on their file names. On this behalf a priorities are configurable for file name prefixes.

Files with a higher priority value are considered more important and go first.

This ensures some files are imported before others for example products should be imported before prices.

```
<!-- example taking from the accelerator -->
<bean id="fileOrderComparator" class="de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.dataimport.batch.FileOrderComparator">
    <property name="prefixPriority">
        <map>
            <!-- default priority is 0 -->
            <entry key="base_product" value="2" />
            <entry key="variant" value="1" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```